# Why is this frame morphism equivalent to a preframe morphism

Tags: logic, order-theory, lattice-orders

**Situation:** I am trying to understand the proof of proposition 5.2 of *Preframe Presentations Present* by Johnstone and Vickers. The proposition states that the lower and upper power locale constructions commute.

**Definitions:** Let $D$ be a locale and write $\Omega D$ for the corresponding frame. The upper and lower power locale are defined via
$$
\Omega P_U D = \operatorname{Fr}\langle \Box a \; (a \in \Omega D) \; \mid \Box \text{ preserves finite meets and directed joins} \rangle
$$
and
$$
\Omega P_U D = \operatorname{Fr}\langle \Diamond a \; (a \in \Omega D) \; \mid \Diamond \text{ preserves all joins} \rangle.
$$

**As a reminder:** a frame homomorphism preserves finite meets and all joins, a sup-lattice is a poset with all joins and a sup-lattice homomorphism preserves all joins. Preserving all joins is equivalent to preserving both finite and directed joins.

**In the proof:**
In order to show that $\Omega P_UP_L D = \Omega P_LP_UD$ the authors define maps
$$
\Omega\theta : \Omega P_LP_UD \to \Omega P_UP_LD : \Diamond\Box a \mapsto \Box\Diamond a
$$
and similar the other way round. Let's focus on the proof that $\Omega\theta$ is a frame homomorphism.

**Question 1:** The map $\Omega\theta$, the authors claim, must be equivalent with a sup-lattice morphism $\eta : \Omega P_U D \to \Omega P_UP_L D : \Box a \mapsto \Box\Diamond a$. Why is this true? (I can see that the generators of both $\Omega P_U D$ and $\Omega P_LP_UD$ correspond. Maybe we can view $\Omega\theta$ as the concatenation $\eta \circ \pi$, where $\pi : \Diamond\Box a \mapsto \Box a$, but would this be well-defined?)

**Question 2:** The authors proceed to show that $\Box a \mapsto \Box\Diamond a$ preserves directed joins, and then conclude that $\Omega\theta$ must be a frame homomorphism. Don't we need to show that $\Omega\theta$ also preserves finite meets and finite joins? (Or is this "easy"?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any locale X the frame $\Omega P_L X$ is the free frame on $\Omega X$ qua suplattice; that is, frame homomomorphisms from $\Omega P_L X$ to $\Omega Y$ are in bijection with suplattice homomorphisms $\Omega X \rightarrow \Omega Y$. The bijection, one way round, is pre-composition with $\diamond_X : \Omega X \rightarrow \Omega P_L X$.

To get the $\theta$ of the proof we are looking at the case $X=P_U D$ and $Y =\Omega P_L P_U X$. The map $\Omega \theta$ corresponds, under the bijection, to a suplattice map $\eta: \Omega P_U D \rightarrow \Omega P_U P_L D$.

Now by Johnstone's coverage theorem we know that $\Omega P_U D$ is the free suplattice on $\Omega D$ qua directed joins. So to define a suplatice homomorphism from $\Omega P_U D$ to any $\Omega Y$ we must defined a directed join preserving map from $\Omega D$ to $\Omega Y$ (no need to preserve meets). The map that they use to define $\eta$ is $\square_X : \Omega X \rightarrow \Omega P_U X$ followed by $\diamond_{P_U X} : \Omega P_U X \rightarrow \Omega P_L P_U X$ (both of these preserve directed joins so their composition preserves directed joins).

Follow much the same logic to define a frame homomorphism in the other direction, reversing the finitary data; though you'll need the preframe coverage theorem rather than Johnstone's coverage theorem. That you have an isomorphism follows by the naturality of the bijections involved.

*Comment*

Not only do the upper and lower power locale functors commute but so too do their monads. This means that another monad can be defined as their composition, in either order: we get the double power locale monad whose points can be given an entirely categorical characterization as certain natural transformations.

It's great that someone is looking at this proof as it is the birth place of the double power locale monad, in my thinking at least. These power monads came from computer science as power domains but they can also be used to characterise geometric morphisms so potentially have a deep role in mathematics.